# RestSharp .Net Core Ignore SSL/TLS

Tags: asp.net-core, restsharp

I do have application that uses the following trick:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Now I´m porting this to .NET Core WebAPI and I just realize that .net core does not have `ServicePointManager`.

Can someone point me how to ignore SSL/TLS when requesting by RestSharp?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to ignore SSL/TLS errors in production.

Comment: Why does this response that it's a bad idea always come up when someone asks this question? Everyone knows that. Sometimes you are in development/debug mode and you don't want to take time to set up PKI.

Comment: Angelo Bestetti did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: On the new Core 3.1 or NET 5 is supported